# Understanding forces and inertial reference frames

Tags: forces, reference-frames

I am working through the Newton's law section of the OpenStax university physics book. I've come across a problem that I've worked through but I am struggling to understand their answers, and where I may have gone wrong. The problem is stated as follows:

> Astronauts in orbit are apparently weightless. This means that a clever method of measuring the mass of astronauts is needed to monitor their mass gains or losses, and adjust their diet. One way to do this is to exert a known force on an astronaut and measure the acceleration produced. Suppose a net external force of 50.0 N is exerted, and an astronaut’s acceleration is measured to be 0.893m/s2. (a) Calculate her mass. (b) By exerting a force on the astronaut, the vehicle in which she orbits experiences an equal and opposite force. Use this knowledge to find an equation for the acceleration of the system (astronaut and spaceship) that would be measured by a nearby observer. (c) Discuss how this would affect the measurement of the astronaut’s acceleration. Propose a method by which recoil of the vehicle is avoided.

(a)

$\vec{F}_{net} = m\vec{a}$

$F_{net} = ma$

$50N = m(0.893 \frac{m}{s^2})$

$m = 56kg$

This part was straight forward.

(b)

Since the forces are equal and opposite then:

$F_s = -F_a$

$m_sa_s = -m_aa_a$

$m_sa_s -m_aa_a = 0$

$\frac{1}{m_sm_a}(m_sa_s -m_aa_a) = 0$

$\frac{a_s}{m_a} - \frac{a_a}{m_s} = 0$

$\frac{a_s}{m_a} = \frac{a_a}{m_s}$

and so they are shown to be proportional. This is as far as I could get to answer the question implying a single equation to relate them. However, the book gives:

$a_s = \frac{m_aa_a}{m_s}$

Which is consistent with my equation when taken through for the acceleration of the ship. The way the book arrived at this (and Chegg, which I used to check for a better explanation that didn't exist) began with:

$\vec{F}_s = \vec{F}_a$

Which isn't true, since the are equal and opposite (though manipulation from this point shows the same answer).

(c) However threw me for a loop. My explanation was as follows:

> It would appear to an outside observer that all internal forces cancel and so no acceleration could be measured externally. If the measurement is adjusted to the frame of the astronaut the acceleration would be shown.

But the given answer is:

> If an external force that is not the ship is applied to the astronaut the acceleration could be measured.

But this confused me because there's no statement claiming this force came from the ship. I had assumed that something shoved the astronaut with the 50.0 newtons of force. Importantly, why is a ship she is *orbiting* experiencing an equal and opposite force? Wouldn't this imply she was shoved and *hit* the ship with $F_a$?

With all this being said, I am looking for help on (b) and (c) to understand how they arrived at their answer and how far off I actually am. Usually it is easy for me gauge but this time it isn't. I can't tell if the question is written poorly or I am misunderstanding.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you are objecting to the following phrase:

> Use this knowledge to find an equation for the acceleration of the
> system (astronaut and spaceship)

As compared to stating it as follows:

> Use this knowledge to find an equation for the acceleration of the
> common center of mass of astronaut and spaceship

Of course: asking about acceleration of the *common center of mass* of astronaut and spaceship would not make sense.

So I'm inclined to agree that it is unclear why the description in the openStax problem adds in parentheses: '(astronaut and spaceship)'.

A better formulation, it seems, would have been to suggest there is a fleet of spaceships, in formation, maintaining to whithin some tolerance that no ship of the fleet has a velocity relative to the others. The procedure to find the mass of a person inside will cause a corresponding opposite acceleration of the frame of the spaceship, which can be measured. (It can be measured both by a sufficiently sensitive accelerometer affixed to the frame of the spaceship, or by sufficiently sensitive distance monitoring of the relative distances of the ships of the fleet.)

Comment: I see. Yes I would've never guessed it to be your explanation though that would make sense. I assume in this case the astronaut would have to be pushed from some $x_0$ on the spaceship, which would impart the desired 50N of force on the ship and cause the acceleration in the opposite direction (which would then be detectable by some super-sensitive accelerometer). I think I was lost in the details of the question because the _manner_ in which the acceleration is imposed is left vague enough to interpretation. Thank you for for taking the time to answer!